# ALT+TAB and scroll MDI Application open forms

Tags: delphi, tabs, mdi

Goodevening everyone,

I've a question about a functionality i want to add on my Delphi MDI Application.
Often my users keep more than one forms open at the same time and these forms are almost always maximized. I need something like a the Alt+Tab that with a keyboard shortcut let the user scroll the already-open forms with a simple preview that helps to choose the right form.

The best option that i can imagine, is something that let me include every open forms into the "windows alt+tab" user interface and manage all the necessary windows messages on the main form of my MDI Application to bring to front the right forms.
Recently Firefox add something like that and i need to include the same thing my Application.

I've searched this thing on the web but i haven't found anything.
Any idea of how to do it?

Thanks,
Attilio

Comment: CTRL-TAB already cycles sub windows / documents. Just need to add a preview.

Comment: For that the window menu item "Window" existed for decades and is nowadays forgotten, along with CTRL+F6 and CTRL+SHIFT+F6 to cycle forwards/backwards thru all MDI childs. CTRL+TAB mostly only works because a page control is involved.

Comment: Personally, I think it is amazing that new Win32 MDI applications are still developed!

Comment: @Brian, well, actually pressing CTRL+TAB on my application doesen't seem to do anything.

Comment: @AmigoJack, neither Ctrl+F6 or Ctrl+SHIFT+F6 seems to work, but i'll have a check.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, it's a huge project since 2005, so migrating in another platform/framework it's very difficult and will cost A LOT of time.

Comment: @AttilioDM: Sure. I meant it was amazing in a *positive* way. I love the classic Win32 platform (just as much as I dislike modern bug factories like FMX) and feel sad that fewer and fewer people are working on it and instead migrating to strange things like these "mobile communication devices" that are so popular these days (apparently they are called "smartphones" -- I have never owned such a device). It makes me *happy* that even the "oldest" parts of Win32 -- like the MDI interface -- are still used! Regarding MDI, I do like that interface, except for the obvious multimon issue.

Comment: New MDI application, save and run. Open a couple child forms and CTRL-TAB cycles between them here,  (Delphi 10.4.1).